# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel keeps moving up when sliding control left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap 3.3 carousel (code taken straight from getbootstrap.com) keeps moving up to the browser top everytime I navigate/slide with the controls to the left or right.

So if the carousel is in the middle of the page, and you start sliding manually, it moves the entire page up until the carousel hits the browser top.

Example here: http://crevisio.com/branding/pLXAsNJdn

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that cause the web to scroll up:

```
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
if (  locationPath == thisPath
&& (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
&& this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
  var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
  if (target) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $(this).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 800, function() { // <== DISABLE THIS AND THE NEXT 2 LINES
        location.hash = target;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

});

The question is - why do you bind the click event to every A element with href attribute containing `#`?

Comment: But I am loading images into the slides, and since it needs to be responsive and should scale proportionally, I cannot define a fixed height. All images have the same size, so the height as such is given / fixed.

Comment: @rainerbrunotte I'm sorry I cannot be more helpful, i't difficult to understand without live example of the problem - There could be more than one solution to your problem, but it's too vague without the example

Comment: I added the example link above, thank you! You will see that when you scroll all the way up on the page, and then navigate left right with the carousel slider, the entire carousel moves up until it hits the browser top

Comment: @rainerbrunotte - I've updated my answer - hope it will help you

Comment: awesome! it works! that was the issue! and well, I don't know why I linked it to every A element, I just took the code for another scroller on my website, and did not pay attention that it actually affected other A links as well! haha! thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

`href="#carousel-branding-project"` in your carousel's HTML definition is causing your page to be linked to `id="carousel-branding-project"`, which is the parent div of your carousel.

If you need that to be an anchor, try changing the link to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

```
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="javascript:void(0)"role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
```

Comment: Thanks! However it does not work ... I took the original code straight from here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel, and there it does not move up ...

Comment: It must be something in one of your other scripts you have on the page. Try to create a JSFiddle with the minimum amount of code you need to replicate the issue so we can isolate it.

Comment: Yes, it actually was, I had another JS script for another part of my site which messed it up, see above! Thanks for your help though!